# How can I prevent the null error while get the children with lambda?

Tags: wpf

I wanna get all the Button in the grid which content is "234" and set them to "123" by lambda.

I do it like this:

```
Grid.Children.OfType<Button>().Single(Child => Child.Content.ToString() == "234").Content="123";
```

But now the question is: visual studio reports an error(System.InvalidOperationException) that cannot get any element from it. For example, there are no buttons with the content "234" or there are no buttons in the Grid.

How can I deal with it? Would you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
 Grid.Children.OfType<Button>().Where(Child => Child.Content.ToString() == "234").All(x =>
            {
                x.Content = "123";
                return true;
            });
```